# How to get an image to stick to the bottom of a div AND overlap the div above it

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to get an image to stick to the bottom of one div AND overlap the div above it.

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5U34m/1/

There are 2 divs side by side the image in the right side
- if the content of the left is shorter than the right, the image should overlap the row above it
- if the content of the left is longer than the height of the image then the image should stick to the bottom of the right div. 
- the image should also be centered in the div

here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container clearfix">

    <div class="wrap header">

        <div class="grid_6 logo">
            <img src="http://cba.thelibertylab.com/wp-content/uploads/cba-logo-placeholder.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 phone">
            <!-- <p>p. 905-579-5302</p> -->
        </div>

    </div>  

    <div class="wrap upper-content">

        <div class="grid_6">
            <p>Nunc id porttitor lectus, et auctor ante. Morbi ullamcorper quam in leo auctor tempor. </p>
            <p> Morbi a enim nibh. Vestibulum molestie augue libero, vitae fringilla massa eleifend quis. </p>


        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 headshot"><div class="img-container"><img src="http://www.manncontractors.com.au/media/pics/site/imagecache/1/1/1176381DF49D6256D968FFB72490208C.jpg" height="400" width="300"/></div></div>

    </div>

    <div class="wrap lower-content">

        <div class="grid_6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p> 
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p> 

        </div>

    </div>  

</div>
```

The CSS on the fiddle does not work correctly - I'm not sure what to try from here.

Comment: It looks like you've dumped whole normalize.css into that fiddle... if possible remove it and give an online link to it in `External Resources Section`. tired of scrolling down in my laptop... -_-

Comment: Definitely need to see your CSS but one thing I can tell you is you're going to have to use position:absolute; to get the overlapping to work properly then you can use margins to position it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is multiple-fold.

You actually want the text to push down the image when it is longer, so your image should be **UNDER** your text in the HTML, not adjacent to it. Your structure should be like this:

```
<div> <!-- First row contains the text -->
  <div class="grid_6 txt>YOUR TEXT</div>
  <div class="grid_6></div>
</div>
<div class="grid_12"></div><!-- This one to prevent the float from stacking -->
<div> <!-- Second row contains the image and has height = 0 -->
  <div class="grid_6></div>
  <div class="grid_6 headshot">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="yourimg.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **The CSS**

1. First of all clear the styling `height:100%;` from `.container`. This styling rule inhibits the element from expanding and makes it impossible for children to inherit height. (Check for yourself in the console)
2. If you want the image to truly stick to the bottom, you will have to set `.grid6.headshot { line-height: 0; }` The line-height property actually inserts unwanted space in elements where you don't want it.
3. Replace `.img-container` property `top: 70px;` with `margin-top: -450px;` (your image height)
4. Set a `min-height` on the `grid_6` div which has text in it, equal to your image height (450px) - your header height (94px) + some padding (10px) => 346px; **If you don't do this your image will overlap your navigation**
5. For `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)`, set `.img-container { margin-top: 0; }` else the image will overlap the text on mobile.

**I've updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5U34m/4/**

> Note:
>
> - Consider using id's to target specific divs. The classes here are quite a mess.
> - Consider using responsive CSS frameworks (% and ems) instead of fixed-width ones.

Comment: Very interesting [and complicated, I would not have come up with that on my own!], I did have to play with the .grid_6.txt & .img-container min-heights and margin-top values for the various mobile views, since the menu changes height at 767px ... but that is to be expected.

Comment: Strange in Opra I have to add height to the grid_6.headshot div for mobile views or else the image overlaps the text below. and there is a 2 or 3 pixel space between the bottom of the image and the text below in all browsers. Can't seem to get rid of that one!

Comment: @SeanKimball Are you sure it doesn't have something to do with the `line-height` (CSS step2 in my answer)? I struggled with that one initially when updating your fiddle & it should be zero for all non-text containers (that's the initial value). Also, I admit the solution is somewhat complicated, but it was harder because of the grid framework. And yeah, I only bothered testing on Opera

Comment: Opera?! [ha! I don't even have that on here ;)] ... I did not look at the line height for the containers, but I definitely will. I agree, I only tried 960 because I was getting sick of the bootstrap bloat. all I wanted was grid+css nothing else. none of them seem to play well once you want to do something that does not fall into a grid nicely ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `position: absolute` for the styling of your image. Then use the `Left, Right, Top, Bottom` attributes to position it as you like.

To adjust what element goes on top of each other, use the `z-index` attribute!